# Status 500 when accessing Coldfusion 10 REST service

Tags: rest, coldfusion-10

Server Setup:
-Windows Server 2008
-IIS 7
-Coldfusion 10

We have developed a Coldfusion REST service.
This service works when files are uploaded to the server and the Coldfusion REST service is restarted/refreshed. I test the end points and they all work.

The first thing next day, I test the end points and they do not work. The return is “Status 500 - The page … can not be displayed.”

I do not believe this to be a IIS problem/issue. If the files are re-uploaded and the REST service is once again restarted/refreshed the end points will start to work again. Funny thing is, just refreshing the REST service will not make the end points start working… the files must be re-uploaded first.

Has anyone experienced this?
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I was wondering, could this be an Application timeout issue?

Comment: I have a feeling that the virus scanner on the server may be the cause of the REST services going unresponsive over the course of the night.
Are there certain directories that should not be scanned by a virus scanner?
When the REST services are compiled(restInitApplication) where do they compile to?